# How to insert .each(function())

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$("table.order-list").find('input[name^="total"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
        valNum.find('input[name^="percentage"]').val((totalTime / grandTotal * 100).toFixed(1));
    });
```

How to insert loop in this code: `valNum.find('input[name^="percentage"]').val((totalTime / grandTotal * 100).toFixed(1));`.
I would like to loop or call all the `input[name^="percentage"]` to recompute the formula.

Here's the link if you would like to see the flow of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Ellyse/47x2N/4/
Here's how it works:  Input values in quantity and try to insert values in the first row by clicking the checkbox, it will auto compute the column for 'Total Time', 'Percentage', 'time Estimate'. Same for second row insert values, notice that the percentage for the first row change but it is not the exact result for that beacuse when you add up all percentage it should be 100%. That's why I'm asking how to insert .each function in this code: `valNum.find('input[name^="percentage"]').val((totalTime / grandTotal * 100).toFixed(1));`
so that it will recalculate the formula.

Comment: Why don't you add `.each` after `find('input[name^="percentage"]')` as you did at first line?

Comment: You mean like this one: valNum.find('input[name^="percentage"]').each().val((totalTime / grandTotal * 100).toFixed(1));? Not working.:(

Comment: could you post the html dom structure

Comment: Why do you want to insert loop?

Comment: Check my answer to see if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: If i`m not wrong, for every `input[name^="total"]` there is a percentage field as `input[name^="percentage"]`. in that case you mean need to use  `$(this).find('input[name^="percentage"]').val((totalTime / grandTotal * 100).toFixed(1));` instead of `valNum`

Comment: I put the link for the flow of the code.

Comment: @user0206: there was a slight mistake in your logic.you had to move this ` valNum.find('input[name^="percentage"]').val((totalTime / grandTotal * 100).toFixed(1));` outside `.each()`. http://jsfiddle.net/47x2N/7/  . i have corrected it, check it out

Comment: Thanks a lot for the correction! But still why do I have the result 64.3, i mean its not exact. Example for first row: quantity: 100, checked the first row, Time Estimate Overhead (min): 30, Time Estimate Per Unit (min): 0.15. The percentage result is 100. Second row: Time Estimate Overhead (min): 15, Time Estimate Per Unit (min): 0.15. Percentage result is 40 but the first row change into 64.3.. it should be 60. When I put tab again in the first it corrected into 60.

Comment: @user0206 I have edited my answer. check it again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After having a look at your code and proper analysis. I think this is what you have been looking for since very long time (at least 3 days) :).

Replace this whole js in your code. I have changed your code a lot. See a working demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/khurram_khu/KYzQR/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    }).change();
    $('input[name^="txt1"], input[name^="txt2"], #qty').on("keyup", function () {
        calculate();
    });
});

function calculate() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $('table.order-list tr input[name^="txt1"]:enabled').closest('tr').each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var qty = +$('#qty').val();
        var teo = +row.find('input[name^="txt1"]').val();
        var tep = +row.find('input[name^="txt2"]').val();
        var totalTime = (teo + (qty * tep)).toFixed(2);
        grandTotal += +totalTime;
        row.find('input[name^="total"]').val(totalTime);
    });

    var totalAll = $("#grandtotal").val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
    $('#time').val((grandTotal / 60).toFixed(2));

    $('table.order-list tr input[name^="txt1"]:enabled').closest('tr').each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var totalTime = row.find('input[name^="total"]').val();
        row.find('input[name^="percentage"]').val((totalTime / grandTotal * 100).toFixed(1));
    });
}
```

I hope this is what you need. If this helps you please mark this as an answer.

Comment: Not working!:( Here's the link:http://jsfiddle.net/Ellyse/47x2N/4/ for you to see the flow. Input values in quantity and try to insert values in the first row by clicking the checkbox, it will auto compute the column for 'Total Time', 'Percentage', 'time Estimate'. Same for second row insert values, notice that the percentage for the first row change but it is not the exact result for that beacuse when you add up all percentage it should be 100%.

Comment: @user0206 It took me a long time to understand what you actually want. Hope I have understood your requirement. I see that you have been looking for a solution since 3 days :) . I hope this helps you. :) Please mark it as an answer.